# redirect to current page after header sent

Tags: php, javascript, redirect

My code structure is like this:

some php code here...

html
head
script
some ajax code here
/script

after running the ajax code, I want to redirect/refresh the page. How can I do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `window.location.reload()` in the ajax request success callback.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with JavaScript; place in AJax callback function:

```
window.location.reload(); //for refresh

window.location = "http://www.google.com/"; //redirect
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript:
http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php

Using `window.location="URL"` you can send the client to "URL".

But keep in mind that this will not work for people with JavaScript disabled (but so will you AJAX-code).

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to follow the ajax with a javascript redirect using `document.location.href='page.html'` as you're already relying on running some code in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on what JavaScript version the browser has, but the latest versions should support:

```
window.location.reload(false);
```

Have that run on the callback from your AJAX routine.